# Conditional filters in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

Let's say I have four fields, `Type1`, `Type2`, `Type3`, `Type4`. What I want to achieve is if `Type1` is true, bring only records which `Type1` is true and `Type2` is more than 2. But if `Type3` is true, bring only records which `Type3` is true. My brain stopped when I need to do filters conditionally. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text. Also show us your current query attempt.

Comment: are these values the same for all rows? or can type3 be true in one and false in the next row?

Comment: Also, which SQL are you talking about? T-SQL?

Comment: @JonoStewart, yes T-SQL

Comment: *Probably* with grouping of expressions using elipses and the OR / AND operators in your `WHERE` clause **BUT** who knows as you did not provide any sample data, an attempt at a query, and expected results. Provide these things and I am sure the community will be able to help you.

Comment: @fafl type3 can be true or false in the next row.

Comment: I guess that `Type1` in your question is both a parameter value (1st usage) and a column value (2nd usage). If so please make a distinction between the two. Some sample data would help.

Comment: What do you mean by "if Type3 is true, bring only records which Type3 is true"? Is your first mention of Type3 somehow different to your last? Otherwise, you are just filtering on "type3 = true"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
where (type1 = 'true' and type2 > 2) or
      (type3 = 'true')
```